# How to prevent Xamarin.Forms.Entry Keyboard to be Unfocused when Pressing a Button

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am basically making a chat functionality, and this is how the XAML snippet looks like:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="50">
    <Entry x:Name="ChatField" Text="{Binding CurrentMessageText}" Placeholder="{Binding MessageTextPlaceHolder}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <Button Text="send" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I have an Entry control and a button control that is binded to a command that sends the text in the chatfield.

And I would want to mimic the Chat Apps standard wherein pressing the send button does not unfocus or hides the keyboard.

[image]

Unfortunately, right now when I press the send button - it automatically unfocus the keyboard from the entry cell.

Initial steps I made to prevent this, is on the ViewModel SendMessageCommand I have:

```
var chatEntry = CurrentPage.FindByName<Entry>("ChatField");
chatEntry.Focus();
```

But this makes a weird behaviour of pushing all the list view up.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had solved this using a custom renderer on IOS:

```
    public class ChatEntryViewRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                if (Control != null)
                {
                    var chatEntryView = this.Element as ChatEntryView;
                    Control.ShouldEndEditing = (UITextField textField) =>
                    {
                        return !chatEntryView.KeepOpen; // KeepOpen is a custom property I added and is set on my ViewModel if I want the Entry Keyboard to be kept open then I just set this to true.
                    };
                }
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }
    }
```

What it does is that it basically uses the Control's ShouldEndEditing event that triggers when the EditText loses focus or if its keyboard is about to be unfocused.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways exist notice that when you press another Entry(or Editor) keyboard remains so tricks needed remove send button and place another Entry there. And just pass focus

```
et2.Focused += delegate { et1.Focus(); };
```

another way is just using one Mr.Gestures.Entry (or Editor) and make padding (android ios custom render) and check `e.Touches[0].X`

but this way needs a hidden Entry cause on iOS [paste] menu invoked so just pass focus

Comment: This didn't worked, and this architecture is a bit odd to use a hidden entry. Found a solution with custom rendering the EntryRenderer for IOS.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked for me. I put a second editor under the button element (just an ImageView) and set InputTransparent to true so that the touch event passed through to the Editor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an item different from a button (for example a BoxView) and attach a TapGestureListener on it.

If you want to preserve the look of the button you can put the BoxView (with transparent background) on top of the button.

Best regards,
Marco